# cyclonedxBom & Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-flavors

I'm not a very experienced Android developer, but I want to include our single Android project into our dependency-track installation. When running cyclonedxBom I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:cyclonedxBom'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:acceptDebugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'version' with value 'accept', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :app:
       - Configuration ':app:acceptDebugApiElements' variant android-base-module-metadata declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm', attribute 'version' with value 'accept':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-base-module-metadata' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'acceptDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
       ...
```

The above error repeats in different variations.

This is my build.gradle (sensitive information removed):

```
plugins {
    id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt' version '1.5.1'
    id 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint' version '9.2.1'
    id "org.cyclonedx.bom" version "1.1.4"
    id 'com.github.mkep-dev.dependency-track-bom-publish' version "0.1.2"
}

dtrackPublishBom{
    host "..."
    apiKey "."
    projectUuid "..."
}
publishBom.dependsOn(cyclonedxBom)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('...')
            storePassword '...'
            keyPassword '...'
            keyAlias = '...'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 27
        versionName "1.0.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".internal"
            versionNameSuffix "-internal"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName- Internal"
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_CONNECT_TIMEOUT", '10'
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_READ_TIMEOUT", '30'
            buildConfigField "String", "WEB_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID", '"."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_SCOPE", '""'
            buildConfigField "int", "API_OAUTH_RE_AUTH_RETRY_LIMIT", '1'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "..."
        }
        accept {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".accept"
            versionNameSuffix "-accept"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName - Accept"
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_CONNECT_TIMEOUT", '10'
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_READ_TIMEOUT", '30'
            buildConfigField "String", "WEB_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID", '"."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_SCOPE", '""'
            buildConfigField "int", "API_OAUTH_RE_AUTH_RETRY_LIMIT", '1'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "..."
        }
        prod {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            versionNameSuffix ""
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_CONNECT_TIMEOUT", '10'
            buildConfigField "long", "NETWORK_READ_TIMEOUT", '30'
            buildConfigField "String", "WEB_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_BASE_URL", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID", '"."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET", '"..."'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_OAUTH_SCOPE", '""'
            buildConfigField "int", "API_OAUTH_RE_AUTH_RETRY_LIMIT", '1'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "..."
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    def room_version = '2.2.6'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //update to map utils 1.1 is breaking
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2'
    implementation 'com.github.pengrad:mapscaleview:1.5.0'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28.1'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'online.devliving:securedpreferencestore:0.7.4'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    implementation 'com.github.pthomain:dejavu:2.0.0-beta13'

    detektPlugins "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.5.1"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:2.5.0"

    implementation "com.github.ChiliLabs:ChiliPhotoPicker:0.3.1"
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.4.0'
}
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I add some following code to solve:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'org.cyclonedx.bom' version '1.4.0'
}
cyclonedxBom {
    includeConfigs += ["compileClasspath"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple build variants you have to define one in your `includeConfigs` property.
For If you have a build variant `fooDebug` define it like this:

```
cyclonedxBom {
    includeConfigs = ["fooDebugCompileClasspath"]
}
```